# Is there a way to implemebnt iDeal Payment with stripe in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement `iDeal payment` method using `stripe` in my `flutter app`, but i am stuck.

> **What i have tried:**

```
RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Create Source"),
          onPressed: () {
            StripePayment.createSourceWithParams(SourceParams(
              type: 'ideal',
              amount: 1099,
              currency: 'eur',
              returnURL: 'example://stripe-redirect',
            )).then((source) {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Received ${source.sourceId}')));
              setState(() {
                _source = source;
              });
            }).catchError(setError);
          },
        ),
```

I have tried and successfully created source of the payment as described in the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment) app
i am using flutter plugin: `stripe_payment` 
but i don't know how to use it and complete the payment.

Please help!

Comment: Hey Lilly, it sounds like you are able to create the source object. Once you have the ID of the source, you can pass that to your server where you actually create the PaymentIntent [1] or the older Charge. You must create the PaymentIntent or Charge on the server as they require a secret key, so this entire flow cannot be done on the client.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the PaymentIntent or Charge on the server as they require a secret key, so this entire flow cannot be done on the client.